# Filtros ou Ordenação, qual deve ser o primeiro ao criar um índice no banco de dados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, índices

Dada, por exemplo, a seguinte Query:

```
SELECT 
  ClienteId,
  Nome,
  DataNascimento,
  Cidade,
  Estado,
  DataCadastro
FROM
  Cliente
WHERE
  Estado = :Estado AND
  Cidade = :Cidade
ORDER BY
  DataCadastro, DataNascimento DESC
```

Em termos de melhor aproveitamento do índice e *perfomance*, o meu índice deve considerar primeiro a ordenação e depois o filtro.

```
CREATE INDEX TESTE1 (DataCadastro ASC, DataNascimento DESC, Estado, Cidade)
```

Ou primeiro o filtro e na sequência a ordenação?

```
CREATE INDEX TESTE2 (Estado ASC, Cidade ASC, DataCadastro ASC, DataNascimento DESC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu encaro a criação de índices como algo que requer uma abordagem de *"tentativa e erro"*.
No entanto há regras básicas a seguir:

1 - *Índices* não acrescentam performance em tabelas pequenas.
2 - Muitos *índices* podem diminuir a performance nos *INSERT, UPDATE* e *DELETE*
3 - Os *índices* deverão conter poucas colunas.
4 - As colunas usadas nas clausulas *WHERE* e *BETWEEN* ou que participam em um *JOIN* deverão ser colocadas em primeiro lugar. As restantes colunas devem ser organizadas com base no seu nível de distinção.

Tendo isto em conta a resposta à sua pergunta é:

```
CREATE INDEX TESTE2 (Estado ASC, Cidade ASC, DataCadastro ASC, DataNascimento DESC)
```

No entanto, se a clausula ***ORDER BY DataCadastro, DataNascimento DESC*** for usada muitas vezes e prevalecer à ordenação pela ***chave primária*** , deverá equacionar-se a criação de um ***CLUSTERED INDEX*** nessas colunas.

Nesse caso criar-se-iam dois *Índices*:

```
CREATE INDEX index1 (Estado ASC, Cidade ASC)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX index2 (DataCadastro ASC, DataNascimento DESC)
```

Os dados passariam a ser gravados ordenados por `DataCadastro ASC, DataNascimento DESC` em vez de pela *chave primária*.

**UPDATE**
A troca de comentários entre mim e o jean, levou-me a pesquisar mais sobre o assunto.

A utilização de um *CLUSTERED INDEX* num campo que não seja *"sempre crescente"* poderá originar tempos de *INSERT* mais elevados.
No entanto, as ordenações são sempre mais demoradas que um *INSERT*.
Deve-se avaliar a relação custo/beneficio.

No caso da pergunta, podemos garantir que o índice seja *"sempre crescente*" se `DataCadastro` for do tipo *DateTime*.

Se você quer se tornar um *expert* na criação de *Índices* siga este [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).
Veja também esta explicação de como o [CLUSTERED INDEX funciona](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/effective-clustered-indexes/)

Comment: downvote por conta do mal uso do índice clustered. Veja minha reposta para explicação (no mais a resposta está correta).

Comment: @jean Você tem alguma razão. Por principio este tipo de índice deveria ser criado com a clausula ***UNIQUE***, no entanto tal não é problemático se o conjunto das colunas representarem um grande número de registos únicos. É o que acontece neste caso, não será fácil haver situações em que no mesmo dia se cadastrem mais do que uma pessoa com a mesma data de nascimento.

Comment: o problema não é de unicidade. Imagine que temos uma tabela de pessoas com 100 milhões de registros. Inserir uma pessoa de idade mediana vai causar que a tabela seja repartida no meio para que o registro seja inserido na posição "correta". Agora imagine o overhead de mover 50 milhões de registros de uma posição dentro das páginas

Comment: @jean Não encontro nada na documentação que refira essa situação. Siga este [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095%28v=sql.110%29.aspx#Clustered) e veja a parte referente a ***Column Considerations*** onde é sugerida a criação de um *CLUSTERED INDEX* nos campos ***LastName, FirstName, MiddleName*** sendo essa sugestão justificada com as mesmas razões que eu dei na minha resposta.

Comment: Realmente vc não vai encontrar esse nível de detalhe no msdn mas veja isto: Columns that undergo frequent changes
This causes in the whole row to move, because the Database Engine must keep the data values of a row in physical order

Comment: Embora isso se refira a colunas que tem seu valor editado algo semelhante ocorre na inserção, onde inserir vai dar esse tipo de problema. Você vai achar montes de referências a isto sites mais especializados para cada SGBD, no caso do MSSQL sugiro o SQL Server Central

Comment: @jean Então não entendo o porquê de se poder criar ***CLUSTERED INDEX's***. Como só pode haver um por tabela este teria que ser a *chave primária*, por defeito é isto que acontece. Mas, para estar de acordo com o que você diz, a *chave primária* teria sempre de ser do tipo ***AUTOINCREMENT*** para garantir que é sequencial.

Comment: Não confunda Ordem lógica com Ordem física. Quando eu disse que os dados são gravados por essa ordem não me referia fisicamente. *CLUSTERED INDEX* apenas força a ordem lógica. Isso é conseguido pela forma como a *b-tree* é criada, que é diferente da *b-tree* do *UNCLUSTERED INDEX's*

Comment: Eu me refiro fisicamente (dentro da lógica da B-tree). O SGBD deixa você criar os índices como vc quiser. Já vi bases grandes de produção sem qq FK e com clustered indexes em colunas GUID. Não necessariamente autoincrement mas é o ideal sim.

Answer (score 2):

A ordem de criação dos índices não altera a utilização dos mesmos.

Quanto a deixar um índice cobrindo várias colunas sugiro que crie dois, uma para os filtros e outro para ordenação pois a engine do SGBD usa os filtros e faz a ordenação em fases distintas do processamento.

Quanto a quais índices criar...

Depende do uso que você fará da tabela, do tamanho da tabela da quantidade de vezes/tempo que você vai percorrer as colunas, fazer queries, inserts, etc.

Eu aconselho fazer tentativa e erro e estudar as ferramentas que seu SGBD possui como profiles, wizards, query plans, etc.

Índices d+ atrapalham, índices errados idem. Leia bastante pois este é um assunto muito complexo para caber numa resposta. Caso queira uma análise mais detalhada crie uma questão mais específica, mas dai você vai precisar postar mais detalhes, como as queries de criação de objetos e as queries mais frequentes sendo usadas, query plans, etc.

Quanto aos índices clustered mencionados pelo @ramaral é uma péssima prática utiliza-los com campos "random"*.

*random: Neste caso quero dizer que são valores não sequenciais, pode ser uma data de nascimento ou um guid. O problema é que como a tabela vai ser mantida ordenada *fisicamente* por esta(s) coluna(s) quando você inserir um novo valor isso vai forçar uma reordenação da tabela (causando page splits, etc). Isso cria um overhead imenso além de que potencialmente boa parte da tabela vai ficar locked durante a operação de insert (devido aos page splits). Portanto só crie índices clustered em campos sequenciais (obs, PKs em geral são índices clustered)

Comment: No caso em análise o conjunto das colunas `DataCadastro` e `DataNascimento`, praticamente, poder-se-á considerar como único, o que não irá provocar o efeito que você refere.