# Criação de índice na tabela

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela que tem 140 campos. Dessa tabela 45 itens são importantes numa consulta. Toda vez que usuário seleciona um item como verdadeiro, meu script monta o SQL de acordo com o solicitado. Nesse caso, devo criar 45 índices na tabela ou não? Os dados estão hoje com char(1) que pode ser S ou N. Mas posso mudar para int do tipo 1 ou O. O que vocês me sugerem? O banco é Mysql.

Comment: 140 campos? Não serão campos a mais para uma tabela só?

Comment: Posso dividir mas vou necessitar desses 45 campos numa tabela. Todos campos são passíveis de consulta

Comment: Quantos registos tem a tabela?

Comment: Ainda estou fazendo a modelagem e fazendo alguns testes de performance e fiquei pensando nesses campos que sempre vou consultar, mas o problema é a quantidade de índices. A tabela pode ter N registros.

Comment: Se a tabela tiver poucos registo (na ordem das centenas) pouco ganha em ter índices. A minha abordagem e começar sempre sem índices. Só quando começo a notar algum lentidão e que os crio e sempre verifico se melhora. Veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38388/2541) onde tem algumas considerações acerca disso.

Comment: Qual melhor em desempenho. Um campo var(1) ou int para um índice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua questão só surge porque a tabela tem 45 colunas que podem ser usadas para limitar a consulta.
Se o problema são essas colunas vamos nos livrar delas.

Se as 45 colunas só podem ter dois valores: "V"|"F" ou 0|1, porquê não tratá-las como *bits*?

Seguindo esta abordagem as 45 colunas podem ser transformadas em apenas uma.

Cada uma passa a ser representada como um *bit* numa coluna **BIGINT UNSIGNED**.

Não sei qual é a linguagem que usa na aplicação que irá tratar os dados das consultas, o código seguinte está em C# mas pode facilmente ser traduzido para qualquer linguagem que permita fazer operações lógicas.

As 45 colunas passarão a existir apenas no programa e serão representadas por outras tantas variáveis do tipo `bool`.

Para facilitar a explicação cada uma dessas variáveis terá o nome de ***'colunaX'*** onde ***X*** representa a posição do *bit* que lhe é atribuída no *BIGINT*:

```
bool coluna0;
bool coluna1;
bool coluna2;
...
...
..
bool coluna44;
```

Vamos definir dois métodos auxiliares para manipular os bits.

1 - Retorna o valor passado com o *bit* **ON** na posição indicada por `pos`

```
private ulong TurnBitOn(ulong value, int pos)
{
    return (value | pos);
}
```

2 - Retorna `true` se a posição `pos` em `value` está **ON**

```
private bool IsBitOn(ulong value, int pos)
{
    return (value & (1 << pos)) != 0;
}
```

Esses dois métodos servirão para:

1 - Calcular o valor a gravar na tabela de acordo com as opções selecionadas:

```
private ulong GetOptions()
{
    ulong options = 0UL;
    if(coluna0)TurnBitOn(options,0);
    if(coluna1)TurnBitOn(options,1);
    if(coluna2)TurnBitOn(options,2);
    ...
    ...
    if(coluna44)TurnBitOn(options,44);
    return options;
}
```

2 - *"Setar"* a variáveis de acordo com o valor que está na tabela:

```
private SetOptions(ulong options)
{
    coluna0 = IsBitOn(options, 0);
    coluna1 = IsBitOn(options, 1);
    coluna2 = IsBitOn(options, 2);
    ....
    ....
    coluna44 = IsBitOn(options, 44);
}
```

Com esta abordagem as consultas são feitas apenas sobre uma coluna e, se necessário, à criação de apenas um índice.

**Notas:**
Os métodos `GetOptions()` e `SetOptions(ulong flags)` são apenas um exemplo de implementação.
Caso não seja possível usar valores inteiros de 64 bits, divida as 45 colunas em dois grupos e associe cada grupo a uma coluna na tabela.

Comment: Interessante esse método. Estava pensando em algo pra unir todos. Vou tentar implementar. Só tenho uma dúvida, a posição vai ficar tipo assim 01011100 ...etc. Na tabela eu vou gravar sempre as 45 posições ou só as selecionadas. E como fica na busca SQL? Terei que buscar os resultados com outras condições e salvar na memória. Depois aplicar o conceito num loop e filtrar. Isso?

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro normalizar esta tabela e nas tabelas que surgirem criar os índices somente para os campos que serão usados como condição nas consultas.

Comment: A tabela já esta normalizada. O que posso fazer e dividir pra outra tabela com esses campos chaves. Mas mesmo assim o cliente vai ter a possibilidade de definir quais itens deseja pesquisar. Ele pode definir apenas 1 assim como os 45.